# intellij 100 cpu usage when plugin "android design tools" is activated

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

any work arround?
have to design on the blind because i cant use the android design tools plugin on intellij due to the 100 cpu usage lag

i5-7300hq
| 16gb ram |
GeForce GTX 1050

i've already tried "invalidate cache"

open other project

close all tabs

Activity Monitor with and without plugin:
https://i.gyazo.com/6dc5df575d416979656e056435846bd0.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please report per https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html if it's Android-specific. Otherwise, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the CPU snapshot: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235.